# Send SNMP simulated traps on Windows without SNMP installed

Tags: windows, snmp, snmp-trap

Is it possible to use an SNMP trap generator on Windows 7 without having SNMP installed/activated ?

Comment: Why not? All it is doing is firing off a UDP packet to port 162 on a target device.

Comment: Thanks ! that's what I thought but I had to make sure. I tried two generators but I didn't get the result I was looking for. Maybe something else is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is obvious as PP said. It's YES.